# Is after_update run when calling FactoryBot.create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, factory-bot

On my test I'm seeing that `after_update` is been called after calling `FactoryBot.create(:object)`. Is it normal? As far as I know, it should be called only when a record gets updated, no?

Comment: You sound right to me, looking at the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_update): "Is called _after_ Base.save on existing objects that have a record.". Are there any associations in the factory that might be added after the record is initially saved, causing a second db call, and so an update?

Answer (score 1):

I can see someone reporting this as a bug, with a good explanation [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/373).

To take the essentials from this, if your factory is adding an association (this is an assumption at this stage - if you could add a little more to your question, that'd be great), the code runs as follows:

**Example factory**

```
FactoryGirl.create(
  :user,
  :account => FactoryGirl.create(:account)
)
```

**How this is invoked:**

```
account = Account.new
account.save! # Since this is Ruby, it'll evaluate this line as part of the hash first, before creating the user

user = User.new
user.account = account
user.save! # The hash has been evaluated and we're assigning the account created from the hash
```

So, if you have an association in there, the `account`, in this case, would be created, then updated as the association is saved.

To setup your factory to overcome this, you can use the following:

```
factory :user do
  factory :user_with_account do
    after_create do |user|
      FactoryGirl.create(:account, :user => user)
    end
  end
end

factory :account do
  user
end
```

How does that apply to your setup? Have a shot and see if it provides a solution - let me know how you get on :)

Comment: @sekmo - did this help at all? Curious to know whether this is indeed the case...

Answer (score -1):

`after_update` will only be called when the object is updated, however if your factory has associations or `after_create` actions, these will often cause the model to be updated, causing `after_update` to be triggered.

An example, using ActiveRecord 5:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :ping
  after_update :pong

  def ping
    logger.info("---> after_create HOOK CALLED")
  end
  def pong
    logger.info("---> after_update HOOK CALLED")
  end
end
```

Creating and updating the object act as expected:

```
c = Client.create!(name: "test")
#   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
#   Client Create (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "clients" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "test"], ["created_at", "2018-05-24 17:06:24.076085"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-24 17:06:24.076085"]]
# --->  after_create HOOK CALLED
#   (4.0ms)  COMMIT

c.update! name: "test2"
#   (0.8ms)  BEGIN
#   Client Update (2.3ms)  UPDATE "clients" SET "name" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "clients"."id" = $3  [["name", "test2"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-24 17:06:36.525448"], ["id", "a3d49153-2f25-48c3-8319-61c2fb6ea173"]]
# ---> after_update HOOK CALLED
#    (0.9ms)  COMMIT
]
```

And FactoryBot behaves the same:

```
FactoryBot.create(:client)
#    (1.2ms)  BEGIN
#   Client Create (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "clients" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Montana tigers"], ["created_at", "2018-05-24 17:11:57.138995"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-24 17:11:57.138995"]]
# ---> after_create HOOK CALLED
#    (1.1ms)  COMMIT
```